# SQL SERVER check field value and send email if null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have set up SQL SERVER 2014 to send an email which works fine using the code below;

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'admin',
@recipients = 'email@email.com',
@Subject = 'Test Message generated from SQL Server Database Mail',
@Body = 'This is a test message from SQL Server Database Mail'
GO
```

What i want to do is have a procedure in SQL SERVER that runs twice a day and searched the database for any null fields and then triggers the email code above to send an email.

Comment: You want to set up a job through SQL Server Agent.  I would suggest you start with the documentation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx.  There are probably also tutorials on the web for this.

Comment: Thanks i will have a look.

Comment: We're using SQL SERVER 2014 EXPRESS so i believe I'm unable to use the SQL Server Agents.

Comment: Then you could write your own executable, and just schedule it through the operating system to execute twice a day.